# Angular VSCode breakpoint hasn't been processed yet

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I put a breakpoint on the line but when I run the project in debug mode the breakpoint becomes inactive (gray) and says `The breakpoint hasn't been processed yet`. Chrome Extension Developer Tools has been installed and you can find my launch.json in the below. What should I do?

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "url": "http://localhost:4200",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: I tried Edge also downgrade my node.js version but it still same.

> Angular CLI: 16.0.1
>
> Node: 18.15.0

[image]

Comment: Does the "url" in launch.json match with the endpoint you want to have? Try to verify project dependencies with "ng serve" and the flag "--configuration=development". Otherwise check console.log and publish what is in there.

Comment: Yes, the url is correct. I couldn't understand the flag it says An unhandled exception occurred: Configuration 'development' is not set in the workspace. In my angular.json file all things are related about production

Comment: do you have the "Debugger for Chrome" extension for VS Code installed? Also try to write "ng serve" without the flag in the command prompt before starting to debug.